# How to increase button width on 'react-native-swipeout' for ListView row swipe (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, swipe, reactjs

I am trying to use the following component: https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout

But I would want the row to be swiped all the way. Is there a way to increase the button width so that when swiped the button can cover the full width of the row?

I tried to add like 'width:200' in the following style={} but the given button width is still the same:

```
component: <View style={{flex:1}}><Text>Full Width</Text></View>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```js
const swipeSittings ={
...
      buttonWidth:150,
...
```

to swipeout